# Object reference to treeview items are changing after undock?

Tags: delphi, treeview, docking, object-reference

I have a frame with an TLMDDockPanel component as the parent, on the frame there is a TTreeView component:

```
unit devices;
...
  Tmaster = class(TObject)
    ...
    devTreeNode : ttreenode;
    ...
  end;
...
end.

unit deviceTree;
...
  TfrmDevTree = class(TFrame)
    JvTreeView1: TTreeView;
    ...
  end;

procedure TfrmDevTree.GetSlavesOnSelectedClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  Node: TTreeNode;
begin
  ...
  Node := self.JvTreeView1.Selected;
  ...
end;
...
end.

unit mainForm;
...
TfrmMain = class(TForm)
...
   LMDDockSite1: TLMDDockSite;
   LMDDockPanel_DevTree: TLMDDockPanel;
...
var
  frmDevTree  : TfrmDevTree;
...
procedure TfrmMain.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ...
  frmDevTree := TfrmDevTree.Create(self);
  frmDevTree.Parent := LMDDockPanel_DevTree;
  ...
end;
...
end.
```

At application start, i fill the 'Data' fields for all the nodes of JvTreeView1:

```
master := Tmaster.create;
Node.Data := master;
master.devtreenode := node;  //I also save the treenode that is representing the master in JvTreeView1 into a master field.
```

The LMDDockPanel_DevTree dock panel is docked at the left of the docksite by default and there is no any problem while the dock panel sits there, but after undocking it, the obj. references for the treenodes are changing so the references stored in the masters (master.devtreenode) are no longer valid. 
Can someone please explain why are the treenode references changing? How to avoid this? Should i refresh all the references stored in the masters every time i dock/undock the dock panel?

Thank You.

Comment: Why are you storing a reference to the TreeNode in your `TMaster` class? There's no reason to do this and you are binding your object to your UI which is bad design.

Comment: Well those references are not crucial for the inner working of TMaster, but you might be right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason it happens is because docking/undocking destroys and recreates the TreeView's HWND, which in turn destroys and recreates its node objects.  A TreeView is designed to cache and restore the `TTreeNode.Data` values automatically during this recreation process, but it knows nothing about `TMaster.DevTreeNode`.  As such, you need to detect when the nodes have been recreated so you can manually update their `DevTreeNode` values with the new `TTreeNode` pointers.

A TreeView has `OnAddition` and `OnDeletion` events that one would think would be ideal for this task.  However, they are inconveniently NOT triggered during HWND recreation!

So you have two choices:

1. subclass the TreeView's `WindowProc` property to catch the recreation messages.

   ```
   private
     { Private declarations }
     DefTreeViewWndProc: TWndMethod;
     procedure TreeViewWndProc(var Message: TMessage);
   ```

   ```
   procedure TfrmDevTree.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
   begin
     DefTreeViewWndProc := JvTreeView1.WindowProc;
     JvTreeView1.WindowProc := TreeViewWndProc;
   end;

   procedure UpdateMasterDevNode(Node: TTreeNode; Destroying: Boolean);
   var
     Child: TTreeNode;
   begin
     if Node.Data <> nil then
     begin
       if Destroying then
         TMaster(Node.Data).DevTreeNode := nil
       else
         TMaster(Node.Data).DevTreeNode := Node;
     end;
     Child := Node.getFirstChild;
     while Child <> nil do
     begin
       UpdateMasterDevNode(Child, Destroying);
       Child := Child.getNextSibling;
     end;
   end;

   procedure UpdateMasterDevNodes(Nodes: TTreeNodes; Destroying: Boolean);
   var
     Node: TTreeNode;
   begin
     Node := Nodes.GetFirstNode;
     while Node <> nil do
     begin
       UpdateMasterDevNode(Node, Destroying);
       Node := Node.getNextSibling;
     end;
   end;

   procedure TfrmDevTree.TreeViewWndProc(var Message: TMessage);
   const
     WM_UPDATEMASTERDEVNODES = WM_APP + 1;
   begin
     if Message.Msg = CM_RECREATEWND then
       UpdateMasterDevNodes(JvTreeView1.Items, True);

     DefTreeViewWndProc(Message);

     if Message.Msg = WM_CREATE then
     begin
       // the cached nodes have not been recreated yet, so delay the DevTreeNode updates
       PostMessage(TreeView1.Handle, WM_UPDATEMASTERDEVNODES, 0, 0)
     end
     else if Message.Msg = WM_UPDATEMASTERDEVNODES then
       UpdateMasterDevNodes(JvTreeView1.Items, False);
   end;
   ```
2. use an interceptor class to override the virtual `CreateWnd()` and `DestroyWnd()` methods.

   ```
   type
     TJvTreeView = class(JVCL.ListsAndTrees.Trees.TJvTreeView)
     protected
       procedure CreateWnd; override;
       procedure DestroyWnd; override;
    end;

    TfrmDevTree = class(TForm)
      JvTreeView1: TJvTreeView;
      ...
    end;
   ```

   ```
    procedure UpdateMasterDevNode(Node: TTreeNode; Destroying: Boolean);
    var
      Child: TTreeNode;
    begin
      if Node.Data <> nil then
      begin
        if Destroying then
          TMaster(Node.Data).DevTreeNode := nil
        else
          TMaster(Node.Data).DevTreeNode := Node;
      end;
      Child := Node.getFirstChild;
      while Child <> nil do
      begin
        UpdateMasterDevNode(Child, Destroying);
        Child := Child.getNextSibling;
      end;
    end;

    procedure UpdateMasterDevNodes(Nodes: TTreeNodes; Destroying: Boolean);
    var
      Node: TTreeNode;
    begin
      Node := Nodes.GetFirstNode;
      while Node <> nil do
      begin
        UpdateMasterDevNode(Node, Destroying);
        Node := Node.getNextSibling;
      end;
    end;

    procedure TJvTreeView.CreateWnd;
    begin
      inherited;
      UpdateMasterDevNodes(Items, False);
    end;

    procedure TTreeView.DestroyWnd;
    begin
      if csRecreating in ControlState then
        UpdateMasterDevNodes(Items, True);
      inherited;
    end;
   ```

Either way, be sure that any code which uses `TMaster.DevTreeNode` checks for nil first before using the `TTreeNode`.